# What distribution does $X$ follow?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have the numbers from $1$ to $n$ each listed once, and at every trial we randomly selected one of these numbers to cross out (if it has already been crossed out, do nothing). Let $X$ be a random variable representing the number of trials until we have have crossed out every single number. What distribution does $X$ follow?

Comment: This is a restatement of the coupon collector's problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Why, of course. Don't know why I didn't think of it.